# Playing a sound file (MP3) with vbscript

Tags: vbscript, mp3

Is there a way to play a sound file (MP3), with visual basic script?

```
Set obj = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
obj.run "C:/test.mp3"
```

There are some other ways that if tried as well but they didnt work.

One didnt display sound but had no errors whenthe script ran.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```vb
With CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX")
    .url = "C:\Test\test.mp3"
    .controls.play
    Do
            WScript.Sleep 100
    Loop Until .playState = 1
End With
```

Comment: it didn't play anything?

Comment: @FroggyIsDank5 Check the path where your .mp3 is located !

Comment: This script is playing the sound once when I run the script, however the script is getting exited but not looping itself, any clue?

Comment: I have made adjustment to your script in one line `Loop Until .playState<>1` and this made to run the script continously, however I don't see this calling my mp3 file in loop

Comment: @mannedear put the code you want to be repeated inside extra `do...loop`

Comment: @omegastripes, thank you, I just moved `.control.play` under `Do` did the trick of playing the sound continously

Answer (score 3):

As @omegastripes answer you, just check the path where your .mp3 is located !

You can also play a stream online :

```
With CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX")
    .url = "http://94.23.221.158:9197/stream"
    .controls.play
    .settings.volume = 100
    Do
        WScript.Sleep 100
    Loop Until .playState = 1
End With
```

So, if you are sure that your mp3 file is located in this path `C:\Test.mp3` , just replace this line `.url="http://94.23.221.158:9197/stream"` by this : `.url="C:\Test.mp3"`
and your code can be written like this :

```
With CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX")
    .url = "C:\Test.mp3"
    .controls.play
    .settings.volume = 100
    Do
        WScript.Sleep 100
    Loop Until .playState = 1
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

You can even to do this:

```
Dim oWmp : Set oWmp = CreateObject("Wmplayer.OCX")
oWmp.Url = "C:\test.mp3"
oWmp.OpenPlayer(oWmp.Url)
```